# How to get nested deep property value from JSON where key is in a variable?

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js

I want to bind my ng-model with JSON object nested key where my key is in a variable.

```
var data = {"course":{"sections":{"chapter_index":5}}};
var key = "course['sections']['chapter_index']"
```

Here  I want to get value 5 from data JSON object.

> I found the solution to convert "course.sections.chapter_index" to array notation like course['sections']['chapter_index'] this. but don't know how to extract value from data now

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var BRACKET_REGEXP =  /^(.*)((?:\s*\[\s*\d+\s*\]\s*)|(?:\s*\[\s*"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"\s*\]\s*)|(?:\s*\[\s*'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'\s*\]\s*))(.*)$/;
    var APOS_REGEXP = /'/g;
    var DOT_REGEXP = /\./g;
    var FUNC_REGEXP = /(\([^)]*\))?$/; 
        var preEval = function (path) {
    var m = BRACKET_REGEXP.exec(path);
    if (m) {
      return (m[1] ? preEval(m[1]) : m[1]) + m[2] + (m[3] ? preEval(m[3]) : m[3]);
    } else {
      path = path.replace(APOS_REGEXP, '\\\'');
      var parts = path.split(DOT_REGEXP);
      var preparsed = [parts.shift()];    // first item must be var notation, thus skip
      angular.forEach(parts, function (part) {
        preparsed.push(part.replace(FUNC_REGEXP, '\']$1'));
      });
      return preparsed.join('[\'');
    }
  };
  var data = {"course":{"sections":{"chapter_index":5}}};
  var obj = preEval('course.sections.chapter_index');
  console.log(obj);

</script>
```

Hope this also help others. I am near to close the solution,but don't know how can I get nested value from JSON.

Comment: Why are you not simply doing `data.course.sections.chapter_index`? and it will return `5`? JSON objects are just javascript objects when not in string format.

Comment: My key is in a variable I can't put like data.key here key is a variable. Actually I want to open a modal with dynamic view so I need this

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker? anyway if you use angular you can use [$parse](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)

Answer (score 2):

```
var jsonObject = {"address": {"line": {"line1": "","line2": ""}}}; 

var modelName = "address.line.line1";

var result = getDescendantPropValue(jsonObject, modelName); 

function getDescendantPropValue(obj, modelName) {
    console.log("modelName " + modelName);
    var arr = modelName.split(".");
    var val = obj;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        val = val[arr[i]];
    }
    console.log("Val values final  : " + JSON.stringify(val));
    return val;
}
```

Comment: we can values from deep json object.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a good solution too

```js
getDeepnestedValue(object: any, keys: string[]) {
    keys.forEach((key: string) => {
        object = object[key];
    });
    return object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to combine 'dot notation' and 'bracket notation' to access properties in an object, which is generally not a good idea.

Source: ["The Secret Life of Objects"](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html)

Here is an alternative.

```
var stringInput = 'course.sections.chapter_index'  
var splitInput = stringInput.split(".")  
data[splitInput[1]]][splitInput[2]][splitInput[3]] //5  
//OR: Note that if you can construct the right string, you can also do this:  
eval("data[splitInput[1]]][splitInput[2]][splitInput[3]]")
```

Essentially, if you use eval on a string, it'll evaluate a statement.
Now you just need to create the right string! You could use the above method, or tweak your current implementation and simply go

`eval("data.course.sections.chapter_index") //5`

Source MDN [`Eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    "course": {
        "sections": {
            "chapter_index": 5
        }
    }
};
var key = "course['sections']['chapter_index']";

var keys = key.replace(/'|]/g, '').split('[');

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    data = data[keys[i]];
}
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible solution that will do what you want:

```
var data = {"course":{"sections":{"chapter_index":5}}};
var key = "course['sections']['chapter_index']";

with (data) {
  var value = eval(key);
}

console.log(value);
//=> 5
```

Note that you should make sure `key` comes from a trusted source since it is `eval`'d.

Using [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) or [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is considered dangerous, and for a good reason, but this may be one of a few its legitimate use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use eval you can do a one liner reduce:

```
var data = {"course":{"sections":{"chapter_index":5}}};
var key = "course['sections']['chapter_index']"
key.split(/"|'|\]|\.|\[/).reduce((s,c)=>c===""?s:s&&s[c], data)
```